# Why does “lactic” have an "-ic", while "unique" have an "-ique"?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, suffixes

- [*Lactic*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lactic&allowed_in_frame=0):

  > "pertaining to milk," 1790 (in lactic acid; so called because it was obtained from sour milk), from **Fr. lactique**, from **L. lactis, gen. of lac** "milk" (see lactation) **+ Fr. -ique**.
- [*Unique*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=unique&searchmode=none):

  > c.1600, "single, solitary," from Fr. **unique**, from L. **unicus** "single, sole," from unus "one" (see one). Meaning "forming the only one of its kind" is attested from 1610s; erroneous sense of "remarkable, uncommon" is attested from mid-19c.

Obviously, *"-ic"* is the cognate of F. "*-ique"*，I don't know why these two words have been composed by two different suffixes, or is there any difference between these forms?

Comment: Because that's just the way those words came to be spelt. As John McWhorter says, "No language makes perfect sense."

Comment: This is English :-)

Comment: Because in English *lactic* has a short /I/ and *unique* has a long /i:/.

Comment: While you're at it, maybe explain the two spellings *technic* and *technique*.

Comment: [Unique](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unique) doesn't rhyme with [eunuch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eunuch) either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most words ending in "-ic" show an anglicization of the Greek suffix -*ikos*.

Older words of this form came into English from Greek by way of Latin (in which *-icus* replaced *-ikos*), or from Latin "Hellenizing" coinages, or from French borrowings (in which the ending became *-ic*, later *-ique*) of either of these.

These were often spelled with "-ick" ("historick") until spelling became regularized in the 18th Century.

Newer words, especially technical terms like *lactic*, are modern coinages.

Words ending in "-ique" are borrowings from French (and may be French borrowings or coinages) which entered English as recognized "foreign" terms after English orthography settled down. There's only a handful of these in ordinary use: *antique, boutique, clique, critique, mystique, pique, technique*. Note that in all these the accent falls on the final syllable, as in French. Some have "nativized" doublets, with the accent on the penult: *antic, mystic, technic*.

*Unique* belongs to **both** categories. It first appears in English in the early 17th century bearing the sense "only", and is usually spelled "unic" or "unick". It never really catches on; but, according to *OED 1*, it was in the sense of "the only one of its kind"

> readopted from the French at the end of the 18th c. and regarded as a foreign word down to the middle of the 19th, from which date it has been in very common use, with a tendency to take the wider meaning of 'uncommon, unusual, remarkable'.