# Why is there a "ph" in "cipher"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Wiktionary says that *cypher* comes from Old French *cyfre*, which itself comes from Arabic. But *ph* is usually a transliteration of Greek *phi*. So how does it get into a French word?

Comment: In the same vein: [Why does “lactic” have an “-ic”, while “unique” have an “-ique”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84425/why-does-lactic-have-an-ic-while-unique-have-an-ique). You could also ask why is *phantom* no longer spelled [*fantum*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phantom&allowed_in_frame=0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [blog entry](http://blog.oup.com/2012/09/ph-f-dipthong-english-spelling/) by linguist Anatoly Liberman offers some insight into these and other "anomalous" spellings involving *ph*:

> Along with so many other learned spellings, *ph* appeared in English during the Renaissance. The digraph made sense (I am not saying “was needed”; it just made sense) in Greek words like *orphan* and *physician* and perhaps in names like *Philip*. But the scribes of that epoch inherited from their medieval predecessors the pernicious belief that the more letters one wrote in a word, the more the reader would be impressed. The easiest trick was to double consonants (and they doubled like a house on fire), but *ph* served their purpose too. So *turph* ‘turf’ and other monsters began to embellish manuscripts and books. The emergence of *ph*, apart from complicating spelling, introduced a good deal of confusion. For example, Anglo-French *Estevene* became *Ste***ph***en* (Greek *Stephanos*), while the shorter form and the family name (*Steve*, *Stevenson*) have *v*. However, don’t expect logic from English; Stephanie is spelled with *ph* and pronounced accordingly.

In short, one must chalk it up to the absurdities of prescriptive spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: @JamesWood. "The easiest trick was to double consonants (and they doubled like a house on fire)". Yet another good reason was that *amanuenses* were paid on a per line basis.  Doubling consonants and other tricks was a sure way to increase one's revenue.

Answer (score 8):

It’s because medieval Latin sometimes used *ciphra*.  The OED says of the word ***cipher***, also spelt ***cypher***, that

> Etymology:  a. OFr. *cyfre*, *cyffre* (mod.Fr. *chiffre*) = Sp. Pg. Ital. *cifra*, med.L. *cifra, cifera, ciphra*, f. Arab. *çifr* the arithmetical symbol ‘zero’ or ‘nought’ , a subst. use of the adj. *çifr* ‘empty, void’, f. *çafara* to be empty. The Arabic was simply a translation of the Sanscrit name *śūnya*, literally ‘empty’.

The earliest citations have it with a *ph*, and it has virtually never been spelt with an *f* in English. With numbers representing centuries (e.g., 4 means 14<sup>th</sup> century), the recorded forms in English are:

> - 4 sipher, -re
> - 6 cyfer, -re, cifer, -ra, -re, ciphre, -ra, sypher, -re, ziphre, (scypher)
> - 6-7 cyphar
> - 7 cyphre, ciphar, zifer
> - 6- cypher, cipher

The OED provides no citation for the *zifer* spelling from the 17<sup>th</sup> century.  Here are its earliest citations:

> - 1399 Langl. Rich. *Redeles* iv. 53 ― Than satte summe, as siphre doth in awgrym, That noteth a place, and no thing availith.
> - C. 1400 *Test. Love* ii. (1560) 286 b/1 ― Although a sipher in augrim have no might in signification of it selve, yet he yeveth power in signification to other.
> - 1547 J. Harrison *Exhort. Scottes* 229 ― Our presidentes··doo serue but as Cyphers in Algorisme, to fill the place.
> - A. 1593 H. Smith *Serm*. (1622) 310 ― You are··like cyphers, which supply a place, but signifie nothing.
> - 1611 Shaks. *Wint. T*. i. ii. 6 ― Like a Cypher (Yet standing in rich place) I multiply With one we thanke you, many thousands moe, That goe before it.
> - 1660 Milton *Free Commw.* 429 ― Only like a great Cypher set to no purpose before a long row of other significant Figures.

Personally, I am always flipflopping on the *i* spelling versus the *y*  spelling, since I am always write *cypher* and then arguing with the spell-checkers.  It appears that *cypher* is [now in the minority](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cypher%2Ccipher&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and has been for quite a while:

[image: Google Ngram of cypher,cipher from 1600-2008 with smoothing of 3]

Apparently *cypher* is a bit common in the [British corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cypher%2Ccipher&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3):

[image: cypher vs cipher British]

than it is in the [American corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cypher%2Ccipher&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3):

[image: cypher vs cipher American]

So it appears that the *cypher* to *cipher* ratio is about 1:3 in the UK but closer to 1:16 in the US.

Comment: +1 for the thorough look at the word's etymology. [*Zero*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=zero) shares a similar etymology (c.1600, from It. *zero*, from M.L. *zephirum*, from Arabic *sifr* "cipher,"), and again you can see the use of *ph* in medieval Latin.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems as though *f* (the letter) may have had a *v*-sound in Latin, so to represent the short *f*-sound one would write *ph* or *ff*.

Comment: So does this fit with the other answer?