# First known occurrence of the word "technique" in English

Tags: etymology, nouns, history, technology

I’m trying to track down the first printed use of the word *technique* in English. Can anyone tell me the name, author, and date of the publication in question? It would be especially valuable, on top of that, to have an excerpted passage containing the word, in order to infer its intended meaning from its context.

Answer (score 7):

[Etymology Online suggests 1817](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=technique), and it is not difficult to find Samuel Taylor Coleridge using it in his [Biographia Literaria](http://archive.org/stream/biographialitera00colerich#page/n91/mode/2up)

> The  occasional obscurities, which had risen from an  imperfect
>   control over the resources of his native language, had almost
>   wholly disappeared,  together with that worse defect of arbitrary and 
>   illogical phrases, at once hackneyed, and fantastic, which hold so
>   distinguished a place in  the *technique* of ordinary poetry, and
>   will, more  or less, alloy the earlier poems of the truest  genius,
>   unless the attention has been specifically  directed to their
>   worthlessness and incongruity.

The OED may have something earlier.

Comment: That in fact is *OED 1*'s earliest citation; the current online (by subscription) edition may have something earlier. However, the word *techic* (or *technick*) is cited in 1600; as [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84425/why-does-lactic-have-an-ic-while-unique-have-an-ique) suggests, it may be relevant to OP's purpose.

Comment: Same in the OED Third Edition, updated September 2009.

Answer (score 0):

A moche profitable treatise against the pestilence translated into Eglyshe by Thomas Paynel Chanon of Martin Abbey.
[Londini : In aedibus Thomae Bertheleti regii impressoris], 1534.

I'm not sure if this is correct, as I currently can't access the full text of this publication, link to Early English Books Online search result see below:

http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?type=simple&rgn=full+text&q1=technique&cite1=&cite1restrict=author&cite2=&cite2restrict=author&firstpubl1=1470&firstpubl2=1700&Submit=Search

Comment: Since the earliest recorded date for _technique_ in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) is 1817, I suspect that the 1534 occurrence either appears in an editor's note or introduction of much later date, or is a foreign word appearing as part of a block of foreign-language speech, or is an OCR error. In any case, it's safe to say that the word hadn't caught on widely between 1534 and 1817.